# Populating a Treeview by Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following model

```
public class Balance
{
    public string Tier { get; set; }
    public float Total { get; set; }
    public List<Ecriture> Ecritures { get; set; }
}

public partial class Ecriture
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int HDocNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime HDocDate { get; set; }
    public double HAmount { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of `Balance` and I want to display that list, and when I click one of the `Balance` I want the list to expand and view all the `Ecriture` objects it contains.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can output your list of balances as an ordered/unordered list and each of the ecritures would be a sublist:

```
<ul>
@foreach(var b in Model)
{
    <li>@b.Total</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
        @foreach(var e in b.Ecritures)
         {
             <li>@e.HAmount</li>
         }
        </ul>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

[The rest is done with jquery and css](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/)